# Difference between rect and self

Tags: swift, uiview, rectangles, self

For example, the `draw()` API:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
```

It has a `rect` parameter. I've always assumed it's the view, but now I'm not sure this is the case. I've also assumed that `self`, when used in a subclass of `UIView`, is also the view. By printing out the same property of each on the console, I can see that `self` and `rect` are not the same thing.

So, what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw)

**rect**

> The portion of the view’s bounds that needs to be updated. The first time your view is drawn, this rectangle is typically the entire visible bounds of your view. However, during subsequent drawing operations, the rectangle may specify only part of your view.

**self** : is the view itself

Comment: I still don't really get the difference. Doesn't the whole view "need to be updated"?

Comment: Not necessarily, no. That's the point. "During subsequent drawing operations, the rectangle may specify only part of your view."

Comment: rect is where the view laids in terms of location , self is the object of the current view where you can access the properties of the class and process them

Comment: @matt it's the documentation

Comment: @Sh_Khan I'm not talking to you, I'm talking to the OP

Comment: Would `self.frame` be the same as `rect` then?

Comment: rect is the bounds of the view not the frame

Comment: if say the view's frame is (100,100,200,300) , then rect is (0,0,200,300)

Comment: @Sh_Khan `rect` may be any portion of the view's bounds. It may not always be the whole bounds.

Comment: @rmaddy I speak in terms of the first time the view is drawn , I wanted to clarify the difference between it and frame

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `rect` is an instance of the `CGRect` struct, which is a Core Graphics struct simply defining a rectangle on the screen, or part of a `UIView`. It can be initiated in a number of ways (using corner coordinates, dimensions etc). You can read more in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect).

The term `self` is not related to `rect`. As is typical of many [object-orientated programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) languages, `self` refers to the instance of the class your code is in. In iOS development, this is commonly within a `UIViewController` subclass, where `self` always refers to that instance of the view controller.